# MySQL automaticly insert data in to other table after insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, insert

I currently have 2 tables

1. Users

   - user_id
   - username
   - password
   - email
2. Wallet

   - wallet_id
   - user_id
   - credit

Now when I insert a user into the user table I also want to automatically create a wallet for this user. 
I thought this would be possible with the trigger events in MySQL with an `AFTER INSERT`

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `pay`.`user_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `user` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO wallets (wallet_id, credit)
VALUES (current_user(user_id), 0); 

)
END
```

How do I go about doing this? (I work with MySQL Workbench)

Comment: Read up on `NEW` and `OLD` in Triggers

Comment: Also, looking at your table schema,  you should move wallet_id out of user table, and instead have a user_id field in wallet table (for normalization)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yeah you're right, it's just a real quick simple setup. But I'll change it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the relevant code for the trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_user_added 
AFTER INSERT ON Users
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO Wallets (user_id, credit)
VALUES (NEW.user_id, 0.0);
```

#### Here's the complete working code.  https://paiza.io/projects/FIpYIdpxg660G7gutjh-mA?language=mysql

Click the <kbd>Run</kbd> button and see how the code is inserting 2 rows in the `Users` table and the trigger then adds the 2 new `user_id`s with `0` credit into the `Wallets` table.

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (
user_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
user_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
user_password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Wallets` (
user_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
credit decimal(10,2) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);

CREATE TRIGGER new_usert_added 
AFTER INSERT ON Users
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO Wallets (user_id, credit)
VALUES (NEW.user_id, 0.0);

INSERT INTO Users (user_id, user_name, user_password, email) 
VALUES ('A0001', 'John', 'sdg42fbg','john@doe.com');
INSERT INTO Users (user_id, user_name, user_password, email) 
VALUES ('A0002', 'Jane', 'Gh5sd46bW','jane@doe.com');

SELECT * FROM Users;
SELECT * FROM Wallets;
```

Like someone else has suggested in comments, if you are creating 1 wallet per user, you should use the `user_id` as the Foreign key in the `Wallets` table.

Comment: Thank you very much!! You were a great help!